# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference , while using evaluateJavascript

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-webview, evaluatejavascript

im trying to get some string return from a webview evalueteJavascript value

idk what is wron here it was perfectly working till yesterday , i had made no changes to this code , but dont know why its giving me this error

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean
> java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

im not even using any bool here , im a little confused what is actually wrong here , please can anyone helps me out

the Main Nav methhod has to evaluateJavascript where the first one checks if the threads page is valid or not or broken

means the `var brokenPage = document.querySelector('html[id=instagram]');` checks of the page contains a elemnt that mostly appears for a broken page or a private profile

this two

```
 "var splashScreenDark = document.querySelector('html[class=" + selectorsdark + "]');" +
                            "var splashScreenLite = document.querySelector('html[class=" + selectorslite + "]');" +
```

checks if the page is valid and is not a private account or an unexpected page thats not a threads webpage

the seocnd evalute javascript has one main elemnt check that diffrentiate between a comment page and post page

if `document.querySelector('[data-pressable-container=true]');` is true it means its a comment page and if false its a post page

```
public void linkValidationAndUrl(String url) throws IOException {
        textStatus.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.white));
        textStatus.setText(getString(R.string.validating_link));
        if (url.startsWith("https://www.threads.net") || url.startsWith("https://threads.net")) {
            MainNav(url, new AccountStatusCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAccountStatusReceived(String[] accountStatus) {
                    // Regex pattern for profile link
                    Pattern profileLinkPattern = Pattern.compile("^https://(?:www\\.)?threads\\.net/@[^/]+$");
                    Pattern post1Pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=.net\\/t\\/).*(?=\\/\\?)|(?<=post\\/).*");
                    Matcher profileMatcher = profileLinkPattern.matcher(url);
                    Matcher post1Matcher = post1Pattern.matcher(url);
                    if (accountStatus[0].equals("true")) {
                        textStatus.setText(null);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Broken Url or Private Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        textStatus.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.orange));
                        textStatus.setText(getString(R.string.brokenorprivateStr));
                    } else if (accountStatus[0].equals("unexpected")) {
                        textStatus.setText(null);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        textStatus.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.orange));
                        textStatus.setText(getString(R.string.unexpected_error));
                    } else if (accountStatus[0].equals("false")) {
                        if (profileMatcher.matches()) {
                            textStatus.setText(null);
                            textStatus.setText(getString(R.string.profile_link));
                            Intent iPr = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
                            startActivity(iPr);

                        } else if (post1Matcher.find()) {
                            textStatus.setText(null);
                            if (accountStatus[1].equals("true")) {
                                //Navigate to comment page
                                textStatus.setText("Comment Link Provided");
                                Intent iC = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CommentActivity.class);
                                startActivity(iC);
                            } else if (accountStatus[1].equals("false")) {
                                // Navigate to post page
                                textStatus.setText("Post Link Provided");
                                Intent iP = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PostActivity.class);
                                startActivity(iP);
                            } else if (accountStatus[1].equals("unexpected")) {
                                textStatus.setText(null);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                textStatus.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.orange));
                                textStatus.setText(getString(R.string.unexpected_error));

                            }
                        } else {
                            textStatus.setText(null);
                            textStatus.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.orange));
                            textStatus.setText(getString(R.string.threadlink_invaliddataurl));
                        }
                    }else {
                        textStatus.setText(null);
                        textStatus.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.orange));
                        textStatus.setText("Unable To Get Data");
                    }
                }

            });


        } else if ((!url.startsWith("https://")) && (url.contains("www.threads.net") || url.contains("threads.net"))) {

            textStatus.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.orange));
            textStatus.setText(getString(R.string.threadLink_NoHttps));


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invailed Url", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            textStatus.setText(null);
            textStatus.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.orange));
            textStatus.setText(getString(R.string.threadLink_False));
        }

    }

    public void MainNav(String profileUrl, AccountStatusCallback callback) {
        final String[] AccountAndCommentStatus = {null, null};
        String selectorsdark = "\"_9dls __fb-dark-mode\"";
        String selectorslite = "\"_9dls __fb-light-mode\"";
        AtomicInteger evaluationCounter = new AtomicInteger(); // Define the evaluationCounter here
        webView.loadUrl(profileUrl);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // Delay the JavaScript execution by 2000 milliseconds (2 seconds)
                // Execute JavaScript to get the account status
                new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
                    webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript: var brokenPage = document.querySelector('html[id=instagram]');\n" +
                            "var splashScreenDark = document.querySelector('html[class=" + selectorsdark + "]');" +
                            "var splashScreenLite = document.querySelector('html[class=" + selectorslite + "]');" +
                            "var pageAvailability = 'null';\n" +
                            "if (brokenPage) {\n" +
                            "    pageAvailability = 'true';\n" +
                            "}else if (splashScreenDark || splashScreenLite){\n" +
                            "    pageAvailability = 'false'\n" +
                            "}else{pageAvailability = 'null'}\n" +
                            "pageAvailability;", value -> {
                        if (value != null) {
                            // Remove the double quotes around the value
                            value = value.replace("\"", "");

                            switch (value) {
                                case "true":
                                    AccountAndCommentStatus[0] = "true";
                                    break;
                                case "false":
                                    AccountAndCommentStatus[0] = "false";
                                    break;
                                case "null":
                                    AccountAndCommentStatus[0] = "unexpected";
                                    break;
                            }

                            // Increase the evaluation counter
                            evaluationCounter.getAndIncrement();

                            // Check if both evaluations are done
                            if (evaluationCounter.get() == 2 && callback != null) {
                                callback.onAccountStatusReceived(AccountAndCommentStatus);
                            }
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Unexpected Error Main Page",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }, 2000);
                new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
                    // Execute JavaScript to get the comment status
                    webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript: var pageAvail = document.querySelector('html[id=instagram]');\n" +
                            "var commentExist = 'null';\n" +
                            "if (!pageAvail) {\n" +
                            "\n" +
                            "    var firstData = document.querySelector('[data-pressable-container=true]');\n" +
                            "    if (firstData) {\n" +
                            "        var repliesElement = firstData.querySelector('svg[aria-hidden=true][fill=none]');\n" +
                            "        if (repliesElement) {\n" +
                            "            commentExist = 'true';\n" +
                            "        } else { commentExist = 'false';}\n" +
                            "    }\n" +
                            "}\n" +
                            "commentExist;\n", value -> {
                        if (value != null) {
                            // Remove the double quotes around the value
                            value = value.replace("\"", "");

                            switch (value) {
                                case "true":
                                    AccountAndCommentStatus[1] = "true";
                                    break;
                                case "false":
                                    AccountAndCommentStatus[1] = "false";
                                    break;
                                case "null":
                                    AccountAndCommentStatus[1] = "unexpected";
                                    break;
                            }

                            // Increase the evaluation counter
                            evaluationCounter.getAndIncrement();

                            // Check if both evaluations are done
                            if (evaluationCounter.get() == 2 && callback != null) {
                                callback.onAccountStatusReceived(AccountAndCommentStatus);
                            }
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Unexpected Error Post/Comment Page",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }, 4000);

            }
        });
    }


    public interface AccountStatusCallback {
        void onAccountStatusReceived(String[] accountStatus);
    }
```